# Fstab: Set permissions of subdirectory

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, arch-linux, fstab

So I have this in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=B6C6ECB5C6EC76D1   /windows    ntfs-3g         defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,permissions  0 0
```

My ssh-folder is in this partition, as a result I need to set the permission to `700`. 
Here's a part of the directory tree of `/windows`:

```
/windows
  |
  | -- ssh
  |
 ...
```

Is it possible to set the permission of the ssh-directory inside of the `fstab` file or do I have to use a workaround like creating a systemd-service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn... I just found the answer in the mount manuals: There aren't `uid` and `gid` options for the ntfs filesystem. This conflict let the permissions set to `777`. Now using `defaults,permissions` works fine and the permissions of my ssh folder are set to `700`. Sorry guys... that was a dumb mistake from me...